# eclipse java resource leak

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse java warning: Resource leak: ''unassigned Closeable value' is never closed

```
try(FileChannel f = new RandomAccessFile(new File(p),"rw").getChannel();){}
```

Where is the leak?

Answer (score 2):

The resourece is RandomAccesFile. You are doing a new of this object, but you don´t store it into any variable, so you can never close it randomAccesFile.close().

Comment: RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(new File("a.txt"),"rw");
  try(FileChannel ff = f.getChannel();)
  {}
  try{f.read();}catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore this.

Since `FileChannel` is also `Closeable` and `FileChannel::close` also does a close on the underlying stream.